# I am using pytorch dataparallel with 2 GPUs. Why are my model's state_dicts' empty on one GPU and have missing keys on the other GPU?

Tags: python, pytorch, multi-gpu

I have a problem with this GitHub project: https://github.com/researchmm/TTSR
If I use it on one GPU only everything runs smoothly. Once I turn on the second GPU and use `torch.nn.DataParallel` , this results in "Missing key(s) in state_dict":

```
[2021-08-03 09:01:00,829] - [trainer.py file line:70] - INFO: Current epoch learning rate: 1.000000e-04
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/rwthfs/rz/cluster/home/ps815691/git/TTSR/main.py", line 53, in <module>
    t.train(current_epoch=epoch, is_init=False)
  File "/rwthfs/rz/cluster/home/ps815691/git/TTSR/trainer.py", line 126, in train
    sr_lv1, sr_lv2, sr_lv3 = self.model(sr=sr) 
  File "/home/ps815691/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ps815691/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 167, in forward
    outputs = self.parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs)
  File "/home/ps815691/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 177, in parallel_apply
    return parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs, self.device_ids[:len(replicas)])
  File "/home/ps815691/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py", line 86, in parallel_apply
    output.reraise()
  File "/home/ps815691/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 429, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)
RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in replica 0 on device 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ps815691/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py", line 61, in _worker
    output = module(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ps815691/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/rwthfs/rz/cluster/home/ps815691/git/TTSR/model/TTSR.py", line 32, in forward
    self.LTE_copy.load_state_dict(self.LTE.state_dict())#, strict=False) 
  File "/home/ps815691/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1223, in load_state_dict
    raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for LTE:
    Missing key(s) in state_dict: "slice1.0.weight", "slice1.0.bias", "slice2.2.weight", "slice2.2.bias", "slice2.5.weight", "slice2.5.bias", "slice3.7.weight", "slice3.7.bias", "slice3.10.weight", "slice3.10.bias".
```

I printed the state_dicts for the "LTE" and "LTE_copy":

```
LTE GPU1    odict_keys([])
LTE GPU0    odict_keys(['sub_mean.weight', 'sub_mean.bias'])
LTE_Copy GPU1    odict_keys([])
LTE_Copy GPU0    odict_keys(['slice1.0.weight', 'slice1.0.bias', 'slice2.2.weight', 'slice2.2.bias', 'slice2.5.weight', 'slice2.5.bias', 'slice3.7.weight', 'slice3.7.bias', 'slice3.10.weight', 'slice3.10.bias', 'sub_mean.weight', 'sub_mean.bias'])
```

I do not get why that happens. Let me give you a quick introduction to the code:
The code starts in main.py. First, the model gets initialized from model/ttsr.py. This ttsr model is composed of several submodels. One of which is "LTE" & "LTE_copy". Then that model is put into nn.DataParallel and the trainer (trainer.py) is initialized with that model. t.train starts the training

```
_model = TTSR.TTSR(args).to(device)
_model = nn.DataParallel(_model, list(range(args.num_gpu)))
t = Trainer(args, _logger, _dataloader, _model, _loss_all)
t.train(current_epoch=epoch, is_init=True)
```

In the train function, after a batch has been fed through the model, the models output is fed back to  the model, to get some parts of the loss function (trainer.py line 97). The model then executes this code in ttsr.py:

```
### used in transferal perceptual loss
        self.LTE_copy.load_state_dict(self.LTE.state_dict())
        sr_lv1, sr_lv2, sr_lv3 = self.LTE_copy((sr + 1.) / 2.)
        return sr_lv1, sr_lv2, sr_lv3
```

Has anyone a clue why the error message above gets thrown out? It does not appear if I use load_state_dict(...,strict=False), but doesn't this just ignore the underlying problem? There does not seem to be any LTE.state_dict on GPU1's memory for example.

Comment: It seems like the problem has something to do with refering to the LTE.state_dict from within the model.  If I print these state_dicts, during the first forward pass of the model, before any other code has been executed, it still prints the same output as mentioned above.

Comment: I am close to a solution. Those parameters of a model for which I set requires_grad = True, disappear from the state_dict. They reappear once I set requires_grad = False.